# Silverlight 5: 3D with XNA on Macintosh

Tags: macos, 3d, xna, silverlight-5.0

I have acutaly access to an closed beta of an online application developed with silverlight 5. Within there's a feature, showing some 3D scenes. There have been used XNA for the 3D. From a windows-pc all work fine. But when I test it from an Mac with OSX the Silverlight-App works fine, too. But not the 3D feature. In upper left corner there's a information showing: "Render Mode: Unavailable" and "Reason: "Not3DCapable".
So I pushed [this example](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/Controllable-Textured-3D-f7b1beab) to my IIS. This time from Windows all is fine but when trying to access from OSX (Firefox) it starts to load Silverlight but after showing 100% nothing happens. The scene is not shown.

Does anyone has any clue, what to do to support mac?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately I found some other websites like this [Blog](http://michaelcrump.net/silverlight-5-has-been-released-plus-other-info) (see the 3. FAQ) and this [Blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/eternalcoding/archive/2011/10/04/silverlight-toolkit-september-2011-for-silverlight-5-what-s-new.aspx) (see comments) whose say the same: 3D doesn't work on mac.
Sadly Microsoft seems to keep this fact officially secret. Found this [Page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc838247) where I had expected to read something like "3D not supported". Isn't this sad? I thought Silverlight should be platform independent? I hope they will change their mind and add a support for OpenGL or something like that.